# Android object arrays

Tags: java, android

I'm quite a noob at android programming and I'm stuck on developing an array of classes.

Exampleclass only has 2 string variables declared in it. Below is how I imagined the classes would be created:

```
Exampleclass something = new
Exampleclass();

Exampleclass[] something_else= new
Exampleclass[5];
```

When trying to assign string variables to one of the array classes, it just crashes. When debugging I found that single classes had both string values & their names were appearing fine, but each array was just appearing with a single null value, no string or name.

Is there any particular way to setup a class, or create one, for arrays?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only initialized the array, not the objects inside of it, you should use:

```
Exampleclass[] something_else = new Exampleclass[5]; // initialize array
for (int i = 0; i < something_else.length; i++)
    something_else[i] = new something_else();    // initialize each object in the array
```